# Machine Learning Models for Non-Imaging Medical Clinical Data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling

I am a beginner in machine learning. Since machine learning is a wide area, I would like keep my focus on clinical data.

When I search for machine learning samples in healthcare, most of the examples are related to interpreting medical images like retina image recognizing retinopathy. What are the clinical relationships modeled in ML?

Comment: 1. "Artificial neural networks" can be used to find associations between symptoms and a diagnosis. 2. [The Role of Machine Learning in Clinical Decision Support - Tanveer Syeda-Mahmood plenary talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4Uk88-DOBA)

Comment: 1. [kaggle - Predicting Chronic Kidney Disease based on health records](https://www.kaggle.com/csyhuang/predicting-chronic-kidney-disease) 2.[A Reduced Set of Features for Chronic Kidney Disease Prediction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5497482/)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the non-imaging examples are

1. ECG (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324457712_A_deep_learning_approach_for_ECG-based_heartbeat_classification_for_arrhythmia_detection   ,  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5805987/)
2. Arrhythmia (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/arrhythmia , http://ecg.mit.edu/time-series/)
3. Diabetes  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405959518304624
4. Genotyping : https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4425/10/1/18/pdf , https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/241414v1